# How to choose the same values in a dropdownlist as in specflow outline values

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I'm currently creating automatic tests for an application form which I'm using selenium in combination with Specflow.
In my Specflow scenario I have an scenario outline with a few examples that I wish to use. I have no problem populating simple text fields with values from the example in the scenario outline but I can't seem to get selenium to select the same item from the drop down list as I have in my specflow scenario outline.

[Specflow scenario outline step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Q0p.png)

[Specflow scenario outline example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI1pD.png)

[Sending the data from the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9HuX.png)

[Cathing and populating the text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv4TO.png)

How would I duplicate this but instead of populating a text field I want to select an item in a drop down list that is the same as the value in the specflow scenario outline?

Currently I have the step and the example created but I don't know how to correctly send the data and catch and click on the correct item in the dropdown list

[Specflow scenario outline step for dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3FWi.png)

[Specflow scenario outline example data for drop down items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7POg4.png)

EDIT 1:
Current code I have tried for the layer and steps page

Successfully clicks the dropdown but does not choose the same value as in the feature outline

```
public string MaritalStatus
    {           
        set
        {   
           _driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click();
           _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item']")).SendKeys(value);
        }
    }

[Then(@"I choose value (.*) in dropdown MainApplicantMaritalStatus and Check Value")]
    public void ThenIChooseValueInDropdownMainApplicantMaritalStatusAndCheckValue(string value)
    {
        _cashLoanPage.MaritalStatus = value;
    }
```

Successfully clicks the dropdown but only selects the first item in the dropdownlist

```
public void MaritalStatus1()
    {           
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click();
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item']")).Click();     
    }


[Then(@"I choose value (.*) in dropdown MainApplicantMaritalStatus and Check Value")]
    public void ThenIChooseValueInDropdownMainApplicantMaritalStatusAndCheckValue1(string x)
    {
        _cashLoanPage.MaritalStatus1();
    }
```

EDIT 2:
With the help from Dazed this code works as intended incase anyone ever stumbles on a similar problem

```
public void MaritalStatus(string value) 
{ 
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click(); 
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[text()='{0}']", value))).Click(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi - can you please post your code into your question?

Comment: Sadly I can't post all of the code as it contains information I can't share, I've attached all the relevant and needed code in the images which should be sufficient

Comment: What you need to do is censor your code so that you change very_important_information to be incredibly_useless_information. People often can't click on links out of S/O so I'd advise posting your censored code in order to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use string format for this. I am not sure what your html markup looks like but this will take the "value" you pass in from the scenario outline and replace it in your locator type, xpath in this instance.

```
[Then(@"I choose (.*) in dropdown MainApplicantMaritalStatus and Check value")]
public void IChooseInDropdownMainApplicantMaritalStatusAndCheckValue(string value)
{                    
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//select[@id='status']/option[text()='{0}']", 
value))).Click();
}
```

****Update***
go here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select if you look at an xpath of

```
//select[@name='cars']/option  ---- you get 4 results
```

If I add this

```
//select[@name='cars']/option[contains(text(), 'Saab')] -- you get one result
```

If I change the path in my code to this, I can pass in the value I want to select.

```
    string value = "Saab";
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//select[@name='cars']/option[contains(text(), '{0}')]", value))).Click();
```

so using your code, it looks like you are using POM? You could add this to the page as a method, and call it from the step. Since we can't see your full html though, I can give you the exact xpath for the drop down value.

from steps:

```
string myValue = "Married"
Pages.MyPage.SetMaritalStatus(string myValue);
```

from Pages:

```
    public void SetMaritalStatus(string value)
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click();
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item']/option[text()='{0}']", value))).Click();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem I have is that I need to pass the value through another layer (pages) in my architecture, just like I have done in for the text field (img 3), for then in the steps get the value and send it to the form. The code i currently have for the layer pages is as shown below but this does not work as it does not select the same value as I have in the feature outline

Comment: Layer pages code:
`public string MaritalStatus
        {           
            set
            {                
                _driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click();
                _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item']")).SendKeys(value);

            }
        }`

Comment: Current steps code: 
 `[Then(@"I choose value (.*) in dropdown MainApplicantMaritalStatus and Check Value")]
public void ThenIChooseValueInDropdownMainApplicantMaritalStatusAndCheckValue(string value)
        {
            _cashLoanPage.MaritalStatus = value;
        }`

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. I think you are over-complicating this a bit. You are just selecting a drop down. Make it easy!! Remember, a drop down is a click. Send keys you are writing text to an input.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! A small change to your code made it work like a charm!

public void SetMaritalStatus(string value)
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainApplicant.maritalStatus")).Click();
        _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[text()='{0}']", value))).Click();

    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach that should work.

```
[Then(@"I choose (.*) in dropdown MainApplicantMaritalStatus and Check value")]
public void IChooseInDropdownMainApplicantMaritalStatusAndCheckValue(string status)
{
    // lets say you have select element
    WebElement maritalStatus = driver.findElement();
    WebElement option = maritalStatus.findElement(By.xpath("./option[normalize-space(.)='" + status + "']"));
    // click on option   
    option.click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This sadly would not work for me as I need to pass the value from the feature outline through another layer before the steps, additional information in the comment above

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item']")).SendKeys(value);` this does not looks correct, as you are trying to send value to link. Instead change the method line as below `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu show']//li[@role='presentation']//a[@class='dropdown-item'][nomalize-space(.)=value]")).click();`